# Angular 4 - printing response from onInit in html

Tags: angular

I have ngOnInit function in .ts class, and html file associated with it.

```
    ngOnInit() {
//some code
}.then(response => {
          console.log(response.data.reports[0].reportStatus);
         //some other code
})
```

generally the method works fine, and the log prints accurate results, but I tried many things and I don't know how to pass the response(and its fields) to html file so that I can print that.
Thx for help!

Answer (score 1):

Well there are a few ways. You could just have a variable. For example:

```
yourVariable: string;

ngOnInit() {
//some code
}.then(response => {
          console.log(response.data.reports[0].reportStatus);
         this.yourVariable = response.data.reports[0].reportStatus;
})
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<p>My data is: {{ yourVariable }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the very basics of Angular. You should at least read the documentation before asking questions.

```
.then(response => {
   console.log(response.data.reports[0].reportStatus);
   this.status = response.data.reports[0].reportStatus;
   //some other code
})

// HTML

<span>{{ status }}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a variable `dataToDisplay` to which you will assign the result from the Promise.

```
  dataToDisplay;  
      ngOnInit() {
    //some code
    }.then(response => {
              console.log(response.data.reports[0].reportStatus);
             this.dataToDisplay = response.data.reports[0].reportStatus;
    })
```

And in the HTML just bind the dataToDisplay property like this

```
<h1 *ngIf="dataToDisplay"> {{dataToDisplay}} </h1>
```